# set absolute path in ant build.xml

Tags: ant, build

I'm working with the html5boilerplate build script and ideally I'd like to have the build process deploy files outside of the project directory.

What I want to do on build is deploy my project as a Wordpress theme in my local environment. So I want my theme to build to absolute/path/to/wp/wp-config/themes/MY-THEME/

I tried editing the buildinfo.properties file to change the publish path to ${HOME} but all that did was create a literal '${HOME}' folder in my project directory.

Any ideas on how to define an absolute path for ant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use the directory specified in your environment variable `${HOME}`.  Ant doesn't directly mirror this in its properties.  You might access it in two ways.  First, the directory should be available in the system property `user.home`.  For example:

```
<echo message="${user.home}" />
```

Alternatively, you can read from the environment using a [property task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html) to set a prefix for access.  Example use:

```
<property environment="env" />
<echo message="${env.HOME}" />
```

Comment: Thanks! That's great. Follow up question. Where can I find all the properties available for the ${user} and ${env} objects? I ask because I want to publish to a directory that's higher than ${user.home}.